# Spark shell cannot connect to YARN

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I tried to start `spark-shell` with:

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

Then I get into the shell. But a few seconds later, I got this in the shell:

```
 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@10.0.2.15:38171] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
```

I got this error repeated many times in the yarn log file.

> 15/02/23 20:37:26 INFO yarn.YarnAllocationHandler: Completed container
>   container_1424684000430_0001_02_000002 (state: COMPLETE, exit status:
>   1) 15/02/23 20:37:26 INFO yarn.YarnAllocationHandler: Container marked
>   as failed: container_1424684000430_0001_02_000002. Exit status: 1.
>   Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch. Container id:
>   container_1424684000430_0001_02_000002 Exit code: 1 Stack trace:
>   ExitCodeException exitCode=1:     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

I also noticed this line:

```
15/02/23 21:00:20 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Setting up executor with commands: List($JAVA_HOME/bin/java, -server, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p', -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m , -Djava.io.tmpdir=$PWD/tmp, '-Dspark.driver.port=33837', -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR>, org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend, akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.2.15:33837/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler, 4, vbox-lubuntu, 1, application_1424684000430_0003, 1>, <LOG_DIR>/stdout, 2>, <LOG_DIR>/stderr)
```

The strange part is **-Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=**. It looks like the variable is not getting expanded. But I think I have defined it already.

**P.S.** spark-submit seems to be working:

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn-cluster /path/to/lib/spark-examples-1.2.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in [this](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Lost-executor-on-YARN-ALS-iterations-td7916.html) thread, the problem is caused by OOM in the container. The only solution is to raise the system memory...

The error message is really miss leading.

Comment: Are you sure it is caused by a lack of memory? I am having this problem too and at least 6GB/per node unused memory.Did upgrading the available physical memory solve the problem?

Comment: @toobee, did you use `--executor-memory` like it is mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/running-on-yarn.html)? Spark will not check your system's available memory. The default value is very small.

Comment: Ok. It seems to work in cluster mode now - thanks so far. What is still not working is yarn-client. I still get this error message. Do you have any idea what could cause this problem in client mode? Setting ram does not seem to help here.

Comment: How about adding `--driver-memory` as well? And how can you start `spark-shell` in cluster mode? Maybe what you are doing is different from what I did, in that case, it is better opening a new thread with more detail of your questions.

Comment: I solved the problem. I use Java7 now instead of Java8. This situation was reported as bug, but it was rejected as such https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6388
Yet, changing Java version did work. Thanks for your help/time!

Comment: I have the same problem running ./pyspark --master yarn-client
I also tried using Java7 instead of Java8, but it doesn't work. Do you guys have any other solution?